# how to read a multiple folders then read single text file and remove header and footer

Tags: matlab, directory, text-files, textscan

I have **30 folders** in **'E:\meta data\new\data _thesis\NCEP\potential_temperature'** directory. These folders are name from 1985 to 2015. In each folder there is 12 folders name apr,aug,dec,feb,jan,july,jun,marc,may,nov,oct,sept. And in each sub folder there is a text file with name **'New Text Document.text'.**

**This text file look like**

```
Dataset {
    Grid {
     ARRAY:
        Float32 pottmp[time = 1][level = 17][lat = 8][lon = 8];
     MAPS:
        Float64 time[time = 1];
        Float32 level[level = 17];
        Float32 lat[lat = 8];
        Float32 lon[lon = 8];
    } pottmp;
} Datasets/ncep.reanalysis.derived/pressure/pottmp.mon.mean.nc;
---------------------------------------------
pottmp.pottmp[1][17][8][8]
[0][0][0], 295.13336, 295.40695, 295.14432, 294.30634, 293.34665, 292.88168, 293.1997, 293.99765
[0][0][1], 298.18265, 298.18234, 297.6957, 296.63467, 295.416, 294.73206, 294.9697, 295.85934
[0][0][2], 301.8217, 301.95905, 301.68268, 300.81802, 299.523, 298.34067, 297.75974, 297.83368
[0][0][3], 303.74838, 304.31403, 304.6887, 304.58835, 303.80136, 302.50162, 301.17197, 300.2617
[0][0][4], 303.41034, 304.0143, 304.78766, 305.5597, 305.812, 305.31836, 304.34036, 303.37033
[0][0][5], 302.32867, 302.09064, 302.47467, 303.53265, 304.754, 305.69733, 306.25897, 306.49597
[0][0][6], 301.52036, 300.1513, 299.69867, 300.3893, 301.99066, 304.19705, 306.58133, 308.39
[0][0][7], 300.62772, 298.95502, 298.16803, 298.41302, 299.84833, 302.60773, 306.06836, 308.72
[0][1][0], 298.18408, 298.39987, 298.05087, 297.1125, 295.95056, 295.17685, 295.21777, 295.94852
[0][1][1], 300.80356, 300.6471, 300.12015, 299.20496, 298.13132, 297.37668, 297.32114, 297.95032
[0][1][2], 303.93793, 303.88782, 303.6714, 303.20035, 302.43033, 301.54657, 300.86902, 300.59802
[0][1][3], 305.8954, 306.39578, 306.81982, 307.06552, 306.86545, 306.1374, 305.02966, 303.8548
[0][1][4], 306.09378, 306.8706, 307.63782, 308.36658, 308.8576, 308.88528, 308.3454, 307.30447
[0][1][5], 305.57605, 305.8617, 306.2301, 306.87256, 307.8137, 308.93948, 309.89862, 310.21188
[0][1][6], 305.25223, 304.64725, 304.3214, 304.5198, 305.5171, 307.47522, 309.9221, 311.8166
[0][1][7], 304.7607, 303.73645, 303.19525, 303.21298, 304.13327, 306.32214, 309.3771, 312.01328
[0][2][0], 300.6052, 300.76474, 300.58496, 299.82404, 298.72336, 297.89447, 297.8466, 298.51706
[0][2][1], 303.76877, 303.57916, 303.0547, 302.10455, 300.96588, 300.19345, 300.18964, 300.82306
[0][2][2], 307.06897, 307.03714, 306.72458, 306.0039, 304.9993, 304.0932, 303.60822, 303.5627
[0][2][3], 308.88574, 309.43393, 309.7199, 309.5405, 308.855, 307.89093, 306.96695, 306.2428
[0][2][4], 308.74188, 309.6089, 310.25238, 310.4843, 310.2196, 309.65182, 309.02963, 308.4458
[0][2][5], 307.66077, 308.16046, 308.5777, 308.82913, 308.9667, 309.2192, 309.68744, 310.15918
[0][2][6], 306.8402, 306.63693, 306.60938, 306.72147, 307.18134, 308.25406, 309.88965, 311.4924
[0][2][7], 306.53015, 305.9735, 305.80243, 305.9749, 306.6974, 308.21075, 310.34573, 312.3036
[0][3][0], 305.61276, 306.0447, 306.27133, 306.0458, 305.46222, 304.94394, 304.97424, 305.58142
[0][3][1], 307.68503, 308.13162, 308.41992, 308.28738, 307.7189, 307.08334, 306.83493, 307.11807
[0][3][2], 309.6904, 310.1134, 310.47327, 310.50168, 310.0883, 309.4409, 308.96213, 308.92227
[0][3][3], 310.9417, 311.27606, 311.60205, 311.70648, 311.4167, 310.8612, 310.34924, 310.20416
[0][3][4], 311.3864, 311.67395, 311.9383, 311.99728, 311.75113, 311.31522, 310.9553, 310.90625
[0][3][5], 311.4762, 311.90808, 312.23242, 312.26825, 312.0402, 311.73047, 311.59134, 311.70203
[0][3][6], 311.57394, 312.26266, 312.76724, 312.87585, 312.68393, 312.50818, 312.55252, 312.78134
[0][3][7], 311.8054, 312.57568, 313.12906, 313.25085, 313.09802, 313.01532, 313.1652, 313.43982
[0][4][0], 309.52737, 309.88763, 310.12912, 310.34393, 310.61826, 310.92682, 311.20068, 311.3793
[0][4][1], 310.85202, 311.2547, 311.46335, 311.60104, 311.77277, 311.99838, 312.2152, 312.42697
[0][4][2], 311.95947, 312.36563, 312.53918, 312.5932, 312.64297, 312.70352, 312.79037, 313.00592
[0][4][3], 313.283, 313.62204, 313.78168, 313.81677, 313.8187, 313.76083, 313.68753, 313.77438
[0][4][4], 314.82013, 315.08856, 315.26907, 315.3991, 315.48166, 315.45233, 315.2818, 315.12057
[0][4][5], 316.1621, 316.40436, 316.62497, 316.86844, 317.1137, 317.19855, 316.99454, 316.5968
[0][4][6], 317.22482, 317.47592, 317.7074, 317.96817, 318.24084, 318.31992, 318.04453, 317.51453
[0][4][7], 318.2667, 318.51743, 318.69028, 318.83572, 318.9209, 318.7616, 318.30066, 317.7193
[0][5][0], 313.5312, 313.9453, 314.21805, 314.3752, 314.54343, 314.83524, 315.2534, 315.67484
[0][5][1], 314.52274, 314.97665, 315.26355, 315.39316, 315.5094, 315.79306, 316.27588, 316.8809
[0][5][2], 315.65692, 316.134, 316.477, 316.61682, 316.68954, 316.84763, 317.1963, 317.7481
[0][5][3], 317.3804, 317.82986, 318.17487, 318.34314, 318.41663, 318.46097, 318.55765, 318.80472
[0][5][4], 319.56302, 319.88324, 320.1243, 320.28275, 320.39932, 320.46033, 320.40912, 320.33353
[0][5][5], 321.5307, 321.686, 321.7823, 321.91068, 322.0879, 322.25162, 322.24875, 322.06635
[0][5][6], 322.89328, 322.96683, 323.02942, 323.13998, 323.372, 323.5996, 323.6675, 323.55206
[0][5][7], 323.90927, 324.02264, 324.1665, 324.34485, 324.55704, 324.71063, 324.75574, 324.70374
[0][6][0], 318.28473, 318.65988, 318.81537, 318.8734, 318.97824, 319.21298, 319.5071, 319.71768
[0][6][1], 319.5236, 319.9052, 320.09097, 320.1746, 320.33182, 320.62683, 320.9499, 321.20068
[0][6][2], 321.1292, 321.51257, 321.74994, 321.91977, 322.1445, 322.4642, 322.7834, 323.00427
[0][6][3], 323.1589, 323.52582, 323.80432, 324.0382, 324.31717, 324.6598, 324.94693, 325.16263
[0][6][4], 325.2939, 325.63266, 325.91116, 326.1671, 326.45514, 326.76016, 327.03604, 327.3037
[0][6][5], 327.1859, 327.48615, 327.7572, 328.00107, 328.24234, 328.48355, 328.72748, 329.02896
[0][6][6], 328.80023, 329.0878, 329.32562, 329.547, 329.73492, 329.90253, 330.11313, 330.42365
[0][6][7], 330.35388, 330.57825, 330.78098, 330.94647, 331.10843, 331.25574, 331.4498, 331.77158
[0][7][0], 323.33923, 323.69193, 324.05307, 324.4961, 324.93155, 325.24332, 325.3472, 325.25504
[0][7][1], 325.54523, 326.00424, 326.52762, 327.0741, 327.59326, 327.98495, 328.19614, 328.2291
[0][7][2], 327.99066, 328.51407, 329.09296, 329.68927, 330.23007, 330.73563, 331.12216, 331.39255
[0][7][3], 330.35464, 330.9161, 331.54065, 332.1248, 332.64346, 333.1716, 333.6926, 334.16855
[0][7][4], 332.6402, 333.2652, 333.90286, 334.4333, 334.841, 335.2709, 335.7482, 336.25653
[0][7][5], 334.89798, 335.4933, 336.06653, 336.4837, 336.76352, 337.04196, 337.3866, 337.79904
[0][7][6], 336.9413, 337.37997, 337.77127, 338.0633, 338.26276, 338.4575, 338.74188, 339.0862
[0][7][7], 338.54584, 338.7809, 338.9639, 339.13693, 339.32178, 339.5513, 339.86868, 340.2153
[0][8][0], 328.92233, 329.1092, 329.50946, 330.10446, 330.67416, 331.00214, 331.06555, 330.97342
[0][8][1], 331.58676, 332.02872, 332.67374, 333.48178, 334.22397, 334.68713, 334.84274, 334.82095
[0][8][2], 334.5247, 335.085, 335.81534, 336.6699, 337.46805, 338.05264, 338.41574, 338.607
[0][8][3], 337.1608, 337.7707, 338.4792, 339.2218, 339.9125, 340.50894, 340.98956, 341.37994
[0][8][4], 339.43195, 340.06158, 340.69424, 341.24918, 341.68753, 342.07806, 342.49316, 342.94547
[0][8][5], 341.45673, 342.0537, 342.569, 342.9118, 343.10205, 343.22882, 343.4439, 343.78824
[0][8][6], 343.09906, 343.54303, 343.9215, 344.13504, 344.19003, 344.1816, 344.26132, 344.4848
[0][8][7], 344.14044, 344.4035, 344.63934, 344.8078, 344.8648, 344.8782, 344.92673, 345.0783
[0][9][0], 344.3527, 344.21225, 344.2381, 344.3463, 344.41132, 344.35855, 344.19742, 344.0575
[0][9][1], 346.46283, 346.54944, 346.78653, 347.1631, 347.5063, 347.6298, 347.51788, 347.26703
[0][9][2], 348.64005, 348.87073, 349.22882, 349.77847, 350.32715, 350.65347, 350.66513, 350.4518
[0][9][3], 350.27704, 350.52728, 350.87787, 351.40756, 351.99112, 352.41086, 352.5709, 352.554
[0][9][4], 351.21695, 351.4599, 351.73758, 352.13474, 352.53653, 352.87503, 353.1227, 353.2944
[0][9][5], 351.6784, 351.97372, 352.23447, 352.46158, 352.64435, 352.8254, 353.0456, 353.3324
[0][9][6], 351.8602, 352.22128, 352.50644, 352.65805, 352.73407, 352.82068, 353.03558, 353.28116
[0][9][7], 351.7999, 352.17538, 352.43463, 352.57568, 352.6638, 352.80853, 353.01233, 353.15652
[0][10][0], 373.08575, 372.7338, 372.34326, 371.99646, 371.65643, 371.20697, 370.60672, 369.9055
[0][10][1], 372.71082, 372.2911, 371.83075, 371.50735, 371.28897, 370.9932, 370.51154, 369.8906
[0][10][2], 371.5292, 371.0934, 370.58093, 370.26956, 370.15436, 370.02594, 369.7519, 369.39352
[0][10][3], 369.2731, 368.84082, 368.38565, 368.1421, 368.10934, 368.0812, 367.98206, 367.85535
[0][10][4], 366.41913, 366.08838, 365.796, 365.69504, 365.76672, 365.80685, 365.73404, 365.6423
[0][10][5], 363.77783, 363.61966, 363.5703, 363.6655, 363.81113, 363.86615, 363.7492, 363.56342
[0][10][6], 361.72824, 361.80392, 361.9593, 362.15137, 362.3182, 362.36063, 362.2585, 362.0247
[0][10][7], 360.22385, 360.49332, 360.74213, 360.91013, 361.00992, 361.04315, 360.9714, 360.81894
[0][11][0], 406.979, 406.7112, 406.48074, 406.28696, 406.1852, 406.15305, 406.13437, 406.00363
[0][11][1], 403.37448, 403.1537, 402.85364, 402.46094, 402.10046, 401.9131, 401.86356, 401.78632
[0][11][2], 399.18475, 398.8043, 398.3421, 397.71506, 397.13434, 396.806, 396.7075, 396.61935
[0][11][3], 394.31522, 393.69464, 393.10754, 392.45282, 391.83994, 391.46332, 391.34747, 391.26508
[0][11][4], 389.3524, 388.65906, 388.17365, 387.68564, 387.20215, 386.86737, 386.67102, 386.52106
[0][11][5], 385.27988, 384.82794, 384.57297, 384.31674, 383.94977, 383.50943, 383.1122, 382.75238
[0][11][6], 382.60748, 382.4421, 382.3841, 382.22824, 381.8183, 381.1771, 380.4335, 379.77554
[0][11][7], 380.93945, 380.90146, 380.85, 380.64468, 380.18054, 379.38736, 378.40945, 377.4682
[0][12][0], 445.32266, 444.59622, 443.80707, 443.02576, 442.36566, 441.9328, 441.80957, 442.01062
[0][12][1], 441.65915, 440.9014, 440.1343, 439.44992, 438.85687, 438.34708, 437.91653, 437.6136
[0][12][2], 438.04483, 437.38684, 436.74094, 436.18134, 435.6574, 435.08936, 434.33368, 433.43466
[0][12][3], 434.92535, 434.40775, 433.80966, 433.25574, 432.7596, 432.18716, 431.3795, 430.33582
[0][12][4], 432.3219, 431.8328, 431.1506, 430.4556, 429.89102, 429.34067, 428.70404, 427.9327
[0][12][5], 430.1155, 429.57443, 428.7568, 427.92917, 427.19272, 426.59174, 426.02005, 425.5253
[0][12][6], 428.26273, 427.66895, 426.8128, 425.98294, 425.24518, 424.53223, 423.82867, 423.29538
[0][12][7], 426.67725, 426.0592, 425.283, 424.60928, 424.0539, 423.38736, 422.62033, 421.99014
[0][13][0], 495.17526, 494.84174, 494.35358, 493.69904, 492.98163, 492.37186, 491.9598, 491.72977
[0][13][1], 493.96277, 493.62128, 493.12924, 492.4213, 491.53836, 490.67026, 489.98196, 489.54163
[0][13][2], 492.5846, 492.2329, 491.8389, 491.2204, 490.3272, 489.31726, 488.40762, 487.79773
[0][13][3], 491.3429, 491.01642, 490.6829, 490.1876, 489.4028, 488.42563, 487.48303, 486.75775
[0][13][4], 490.36655, 490.02048, 489.62173, 489.11783, 488.39346, 487.5128, 486.64325, 485.94077
[0][13][5], 489.41605, 488.9781, 488.42477, 487.73178, 486.9266, 486.11728, 485.38193, 484.8035
[0][13][6], 488.2239, 487.70276, 486.99646, 486.16443, 485.2972, 484.55157, 483.99515, 483.60345
[0][13][7], 486.8873, 486.38895, 485.7194, 484.91882, 484.15363, 483.57675, 483.2173, 483.0015
[0][14][0], 587.2294, 587.0396, 586.7298, 586.23303, 585.7371, 585.5555, 585.6572, 585.8616
[0][14][1], 587.3656, 587.2158, 587.12946, 586.8552, 586.4456, 586.20764, 586.22943, 586.35565
[0][14][2], 587.7952, 587.4937, 587.5782, 587.58624, 587.35925, 587.11676, 587.045, 587.0023
[0][14][3], 588.37286, 587.84064, 587.93964, 588.11035, 588.0523, 587.80524, 587.5736, 587.43097
[0][14][4], 588.5436, 587.9587, 588.0731, 588.3701, 588.39276, 588.1377, 587.87415, 587.7698
[0][14][5], 588.02234, 587.6263, 587.976, 588.47095, 588.64435, 588.5028, 588.3329, 588.3265
[0][14][6], 587.1894, 587.2349, 587.8906, 588.59265, 588.9596, 589.0431, 589.1176, 589.1857
[0][14][7], 586.8106, 587.2403, 588.0759, 588.83606, 589.2838, 589.60266, 589.86957, 589.9459
[0][15][0], 677.61127, 676.9789, 676.3252, 675.86835, 675.6062, 675.4788, 675.53687, 675.9528
[0][15][1], 678.08136, 677.4715, 676.727, 676.1977, 675.88776, 675.696, 675.52875, 675.6399
[0][15][2], 678.3292, 678.04065, 677.3929, 676.8126, 676.4649, 676.28033, 676.16, 676.3121
[0][15][3], 678.8748, 679.0778, 678.6973, 678.10486, 677.7194, 677.59784, 677.70197, 678.08344
[0][15][4], 679.7213, 680.37616, 680.38824, 679.9477, 679.61835, 679.6019, 679.8774, 680.34766
[0][15][5], 680.678, 681.4867, 681.84973, 681.73254, 681.5897, 681.6101, 681.8477, 682.18225
[0][15][6], 681.657, 682.3016, 682.8472, 683.06226, 683.09906, 682.98083, 682.893, 683.06445
[0][15][7], 682.7799, 683.03394, 683.59875, 684.0925, 684.14044, 683.6865, 683.20715, 683.25104
[0][16][0], 872.15247, 875.8923, 879.8187, 882.02814, 882.46576, 882.46954, 882.85126, 883.1807
[0][16][1], 877.0001, 880.11096, 883.71674, 885.3156, 884.8133, 884.1991, 885.0534, 886.70575
[0][16][2], 882.46216, 884.02374, 886.41223, 887.09863, 885.7347, 884.46387, 885.2397, 887.4753
[0][16][3], 885.3889, 885.27704, 886.39856, 886.4322, 884.7113, 883.0353, 883.36115, 885.40265
[0][16][4], 885.0074, 884.0188, 884.4739, 884.63434, 883.3711, 881.92377, 881.9412, 883.43195
[0][16][5], 883.21185, 882.2519, 882.7181, 883.4307, 883.264, 882.8126, 883.18823, 884.2301
[0][16][6], 881.83685, 881.3681, 882.02576, 883.06024, 883.91437, 884.8818, 886.2607, 887.2179
[0][16][7], 881.4078, 881.48987, 882.09906, 882.87494, 884.0972, 886.24695, 888.6479, 889.6661

pottmp.time[1]
1623840.0

pottmp.level[17]
1000.0, 925.0, 850.0, 700.0, 600.0, 500.0, 400.0, 300.0, 250.0, 200.0, 150.0, 100.0, 70.0, 50.0, 30.0, 20.0, 10.0

pottmp.lat[8]
37.5, 35.0, 32.5, 30.0, 27.5, 25.0, 22.5, 20.0

pottmp.lon[8]
60.0, 62.5, 65.0, 67.5, 70.0, 72.5, 75.0, 77.5
```

I want to remove its header and footer so that it looks like

```
[0][0][0], 295.13336, 295.40695, 295.14432, 294.30634, 293.34665, 292.88168, 293.1997, 293.99765
[0][0][1], 298.18265, 298.18234, 297.6957, 296.63467, 295.416, 294.73206, 294.9697, 295.85934
[0][0][2], 301.8217, 301.95905, 301.68268, 300.81802, 299.523, 298.34067, 297.75974, 297.83368
[0][0][3], 303.74838, 304.31403, 304.6887, 304.58835, 303.80136, 302.50162, 301.17197, 300.2617
[0][0][4], 303.41034, 304.0143, 304.78766, 305.5597, 305.812, 305.31836, 304.34036, 303.37033
[0][0][5], 302.32867, 302.09064, 302.47467, 303.53265, 304.754, 305.69733, 306.25897, 306.49597
[0][0][6], 301.52036, 300.1513, 299.69867, 300.3893, 301.99066, 304.19705, 306.58133, 308.39
[0][0][7], 300.62772, 298.95502, 298.16803, 298.41302, 299.84833, 302.60773, 306.06836, 308.72
[0][1][0], 298.18408, 298.39987, 298.05087, 297.1125, 295.95056, 295.17685, 295.21777, 295.94852
[0][1][1], 300.80356, 300.6471, 300.12015, 299.20496, 298.13132, 297.37668, 297.32114, 297.95032
[0][1][2], 303.93793, 303.88782, 303.6714, 303.20035, 302.43033, 301.54657, 300.86902, 300.59802
[0][1][3], 305.8954, 306.39578, 306.81982, 307.06552, 306.86545, 306.1374, 305.02966, 303.8548
[0][1][4], 306.09378, 306.8706, 307.63782, 308.36658, 308.8576, 308.88528, 308.3454, 307.30447
[0][1][5], 305.57605, 305.8617, 306.2301, 306.87256, 307.8137, 308.93948, 309.89862, 310.21188
[0][1][6], 305.25223, 304.64725, 304.3214, 304.5198, 305.5171, 307.47522, 309.9221, 311.8166
[0][1][7], 304.7607, 303.73645, 303.19525, 303.21298, 304.13327, 306.32214, 309.3771, 312.01328
[0][2][0], 300.6052, 300.76474, 300.58496, 299.82404, 298.72336, 297.89447, 297.8466, 298.51706
[0][2][1], 303.76877, 303.57916, 303.0547, 302.10455, 300.96588, 300.19345, 300.18964, 300.82306
[0][2][2], 307.06897, 307.03714, 306.72458, 306.0039, 304.9993, 304.0932, 303.60822, 303.5627
[0][2][3], 308.88574, 309.43393, 309.7199, 309.5405, 308.855, 307.89093, 306.96695, 306.2428
[0][2][4], 308.74188, 309.6089, 310.25238, 310.4843, 310.2196, 309.65182, 309.02963, 308.4458
[0][2][5], 307.66077, 308.16046, 308.5777, 308.82913, 308.9667, 309.2192, 309.68744, 310.15918
[0][2][6], 306.8402, 306.63693, 306.60938, 306.72147, 307.18134, 308.25406, 309.88965, 311.4924
[0][2][7], 306.53015, 305.9735, 305.80243, 305.9749, 306.6974, 308.21075, 310.34573, 312.3036
[0][3][0], 305.61276, 306.0447, 306.27133, 306.0458, 305.46222, 304.94394, 304.97424, 305.58142
[0][3][1], 307.68503, 308.13162, 308.41992, 308.28738, 307.7189, 307.08334, 306.83493, 307.11807
[0][3][2], 309.6904, 310.1134, 310.47327, 310.50168, 310.0883, 309.4409, 308.96213, 308.92227
[0][3][3], 310.9417, 311.27606, 311.60205, 311.70648, 311.4167, 310.8612, 310.34924, 310.20416
[0][3][4], 311.3864, 311.67395, 311.9383, 311.99728, 311.75113, 311.31522, 310.9553, 310.90625
[0][3][5], 311.4762, 311.90808, 312.23242, 312.26825, 312.0402, 311.73047, 311.59134, 311.70203
[0][3][6], 311.57394, 312.26266, 312.76724, 312.87585, 312.68393, 312.50818, 312.55252, 312.78134
[0][3][7], 311.8054, 312.57568, 313.12906, 313.25085, 313.09802, 313.01532, 313.1652, 313.43982
[0][4][0], 309.52737, 309.88763, 310.12912, 310.34393, 310.61826, 310.92682, 311.20068, 311.3793
[0][4][1], 310.85202, 311.2547, 311.46335, 311.60104, 311.77277, 311.99838, 312.2152, 312.42697
[0][4][2], 311.95947, 312.36563, 312.53918, 312.5932, 312.64297, 312.70352, 312.79037, 313.00592
[0][4][3], 313.283, 313.62204, 313.78168, 313.81677, 313.8187, 313.76083, 313.68753, 313.77438
[0][4][4], 314.82013, 315.08856, 315.26907, 315.3991, 315.48166, 315.45233, 315.2818, 315.12057
[0][4][5], 316.1621, 316.40436, 316.62497, 316.86844, 317.1137, 317.19855, 316.99454, 316.5968
[0][4][6], 317.22482, 317.47592, 317.7074, 317.96817, 318.24084, 318.31992, 318.04453, 317.51453
[0][4][7], 318.2667, 318.51743, 318.69028, 318.83572, 318.9209, 318.7616, 318.30066, 317.7193
[0][5][0], 313.5312, 313.9453, 314.21805, 314.3752, 314.54343, 314.83524, 315.2534, 315.67484
[0][5][1], 314.52274, 314.97665, 315.26355, 315.39316, 315.5094, 315.79306, 316.27588, 316.8809
[0][5][2], 315.65692, 316.134, 316.477, 316.61682, 316.68954, 316.84763, 317.1963, 317.7481
[0][5][3], 317.3804, 317.82986, 318.17487, 318.34314, 318.41663, 318.46097, 318.55765, 318.80472
[0][5][4], 319.56302, 319.88324, 320.1243, 320.28275, 320.39932, 320.46033, 320.40912, 320.33353
[0][5][5], 321.5307, 321.686, 321.7823, 321.91068, 322.0879, 322.25162, 322.24875, 322.06635
[0][5][6], 322.89328, 322.96683, 323.02942, 323.13998, 323.372, 323.5996, 323.6675, 323.55206
[0][5][7], 323.90927, 324.02264, 324.1665, 324.34485, 324.55704, 324.71063, 324.75574, 324.70374
[0][6][0], 318.28473, 318.65988, 318.81537, 318.8734, 318.97824, 319.21298, 319.5071, 319.71768
[0][6][1], 319.5236, 319.9052, 320.09097, 320.1746, 320.33182, 320.62683, 320.9499, 321.20068
[0][6][2], 321.1292, 321.51257, 321.74994, 321.91977, 322.1445, 322.4642, 322.7834, 323.00427
[0][6][3], 323.1589, 323.52582, 323.80432, 324.0382, 324.31717, 324.6598, 324.94693, 325.16263
[0][6][4], 325.2939, 325.63266, 325.91116, 326.1671, 326.45514, 326.76016, 327.03604, 327.3037
[0][6][5], 327.1859, 327.48615, 327.7572, 328.00107, 328.24234, 328.48355, 328.72748, 329.02896
[0][6][6], 328.80023, 329.0878, 329.32562, 329.547, 329.73492, 329.90253, 330.11313, 330.42365
[0][6][7], 330.35388, 330.57825, 330.78098, 330.94647, 331.10843, 331.25574, 331.4498, 331.77158
[0][7][0], 323.33923, 323.69193, 324.05307, 324.4961, 324.93155, 325.24332, 325.3472, 325.25504
[0][7][1], 325.54523, 326.00424, 326.52762, 327.0741, 327.59326, 327.98495, 328.19614, 328.2291
[0][7][2], 327.99066, 328.51407, 329.09296, 329.68927, 330.23007, 330.73563, 331.12216, 331.39255
[0][7][3], 330.35464, 330.9161, 331.54065, 332.1248, 332.64346, 333.1716, 333.6926, 334.16855
[0][7][4], 332.6402, 333.2652, 333.90286, 334.4333, 334.841, 335.2709, 335.7482, 336.25653
[0][7][5], 334.89798, 335.4933, 336.06653, 336.4837, 336.76352, 337.04196, 337.3866, 337.79904
[0][7][6], 336.9413, 337.37997, 337.77127, 338.0633, 338.26276, 338.4575, 338.74188, 339.0862
[0][7][7], 338.54584, 338.7809, 338.9639, 339.13693, 339.32178, 339.5513, 339.86868, 340.2153
[0][8][0], 328.92233, 329.1092, 329.50946, 330.10446, 330.67416, 331.00214, 331.06555, 330.97342
[0][8][1], 331.58676, 332.02872, 332.67374, 333.48178, 334.22397, 334.68713, 334.84274, 334.82095
[0][8][2], 334.5247, 335.085, 335.81534, 336.6699, 337.46805, 338.05264, 338.41574, 338.607
[0][8][3], 337.1608, 337.7707, 338.4792, 339.2218, 339.9125, 340.50894, 340.98956, 341.37994
[0][8][4], 339.43195, 340.06158, 340.69424, 341.24918, 341.68753, 342.07806, 342.49316, 342.94547
[0][8][5], 341.45673, 342.0537, 342.569, 342.9118, 343.10205, 343.22882, 343.4439, 343.78824
[0][8][6], 343.09906, 343.54303, 343.9215, 344.13504, 344.19003, 344.1816, 344.26132, 344.4848
[0][8][7], 344.14044, 344.4035, 344.63934, 344.8078, 344.8648, 344.8782, 344.92673, 345.0783
[0][9][0], 344.3527, 344.21225, 344.2381, 344.3463, 344.41132, 344.35855, 344.19742, 344.0575
[0][9][1], 346.46283, 346.54944, 346.78653, 347.1631, 347.5063, 347.6298, 347.51788, 347.26703
[0][9][2], 348.64005, 348.87073, 349.22882, 349.77847, 350.32715, 350.65347, 350.66513, 350.4518
[0][9][3], 350.27704, 350.52728, 350.87787, 351.40756, 351.99112, 352.41086, 352.5709, 352.554
[0][9][4], 351.21695, 351.4599, 351.73758, 352.13474, 352.53653, 352.87503, 353.1227, 353.2944
[0][9][5], 351.6784, 351.97372, 352.23447, 352.46158, 352.64435, 352.8254, 353.0456, 353.3324
[0][9][6], 351.8602, 352.22128, 352.50644, 352.65805, 352.73407, 352.82068, 353.03558, 353.28116
[0][9][7], 351.7999, 352.17538, 352.43463, 352.57568, 352.6638, 352.80853, 353.01233, 353.15652
[0][10][0], 373.08575, 372.7338, 372.34326, 371.99646, 371.65643, 371.20697, 370.60672, 369.9055
[0][10][1], 372.71082, 372.2911, 371.83075, 371.50735, 371.28897, 370.9932, 370.51154, 369.8906
[0][10][2], 371.5292, 371.0934, 370.58093, 370.26956, 370.15436, 370.02594, 369.7519, 369.39352
[0][10][3], 369.2731, 368.84082, 368.38565, 368.1421, 368.10934, 368.0812, 367.98206, 367.85535
[0][10][4], 366.41913, 366.08838, 365.796, 365.69504, 365.76672, 365.80685, 365.73404, 365.6423
[0][10][5], 363.77783, 363.61966, 363.5703, 363.6655, 363.81113, 363.86615, 363.7492, 363.56342
[0][10][6], 361.72824, 361.80392, 361.9593, 362.15137, 362.3182, 362.36063, 362.2585, 362.0247
[0][10][7], 360.22385, 360.49332, 360.74213, 360.91013, 361.00992, 361.04315, 360.9714, 360.81894
[0][11][0], 406.979, 406.7112, 406.48074, 406.28696, 406.1852, 406.15305, 406.13437, 406.00363
[0][11][1], 403.37448, 403.1537, 402.85364, 402.46094, 402.10046, 401.9131, 401.86356, 401.78632
[0][11][2], 399.18475, 398.8043, 398.3421, 397.71506, 397.13434, 396.806, 396.7075, 396.61935
[0][11][3], 394.31522, 393.69464, 393.10754, 392.45282, 391.83994, 391.46332, 391.34747, 391.26508
[0][11][4], 389.3524, 388.65906, 388.17365, 387.68564, 387.20215, 386.86737, 386.67102, 386.52106
[0][11][5], 385.27988, 384.82794, 384.57297, 384.31674, 383.94977, 383.50943, 383.1122, 382.75238
[0][11][6], 382.60748, 382.4421, 382.3841, 382.22824, 381.8183, 381.1771, 380.4335, 379.77554
[0][11][7], 380.93945, 380.90146, 380.85, 380.64468, 380.18054, 379.38736, 378.40945, 377.4682
[0][12][0], 445.32266, 444.59622, 443.80707, 443.02576, 442.36566, 441.9328, 441.80957, 442.01062
[0][12][1], 441.65915, 440.9014, 440.1343, 439.44992, 438.85687, 438.34708, 437.91653, 437.6136
[0][12][2], 438.04483, 437.38684, 436.74094, 436.18134, 435.6574, 435.08936, 434.33368, 433.43466
[0][12][3], 434.92535, 434.40775, 433.80966, 433.25574, 432.7596, 432.18716, 431.3795, 430.33582
[0][12][4], 432.3219, 431.8328, 431.1506, 430.4556, 429.89102, 429.34067, 428.70404, 427.9327
[0][12][5], 430.1155, 429.57443, 428.7568, 427.92917, 427.19272, 426.59174, 426.02005, 425.5253
[0][12][6], 428.26273, 427.66895, 426.8128, 425.98294, 425.24518, 424.53223, 423.82867, 423.29538
[0][12][7], 426.67725, 426.0592, 425.283, 424.60928, 424.0539, 423.38736, 422.62033, 421.99014
[0][13][0], 495.17526, 494.84174, 494.35358, 493.69904, 492.98163, 492.37186, 491.9598, 491.72977
[0][13][1], 493.96277, 493.62128, 493.12924, 492.4213, 491.53836, 490.67026, 489.98196, 489.54163
[0][13][2], 492.5846, 492.2329, 491.8389, 491.2204, 490.3272, 489.31726, 488.40762, 487.79773
[0][13][3], 491.3429, 491.01642, 490.6829, 490.1876, 489.4028, 488.42563, 487.48303, 486.75775
[0][13][4], 490.36655, 490.02048, 489.62173, 489.11783, 488.39346, 487.5128, 486.64325, 485.94077
[0][13][5], 489.41605, 488.9781, 488.42477, 487.73178, 486.9266, 486.11728, 485.38193, 484.8035
[0][13][6], 488.2239, 487.70276, 486.99646, 486.16443, 485.2972, 484.55157, 483.99515, 483.60345
[0][13][7], 486.8873, 486.38895, 485.7194, 484.91882, 484.15363, 483.57675, 483.2173, 483.0015
[0][14][0], 587.2294, 587.0396, 586.7298, 586.23303, 585.7371, 585.5555, 585.6572, 585.8616
[0][14][1], 587.3656, 587.2158, 587.12946, 586.8552, 586.4456, 586.20764, 586.22943, 586.35565
[0][14][2], 587.7952, 587.4937, 587.5782, 587.58624, 587.35925, 587.11676, 587.045, 587.0023
[0][14][3], 588.37286, 587.84064, 587.93964, 588.11035, 588.0523, 587.80524, 587.5736, 587.43097
[0][14][4], 588.5436, 587.9587, 588.0731, 588.3701, 588.39276, 588.1377, 587.87415, 587.7698
[0][14][5], 588.02234, 587.6263, 587.976, 588.47095, 588.64435, 588.5028, 588.3329, 588.3265
[0][14][6], 587.1894, 587.2349, 587.8906, 588.59265, 588.9596, 589.0431, 589.1176, 589.1857
[0][14][7], 586.8106, 587.2403, 588.0759, 588.83606, 589.2838, 589.60266, 589.86957, 589.9459
[0][15][0], 677.61127, 676.9789, 676.3252, 675.86835, 675.6062, 675.4788, 675.53687, 675.9528
[0][15][1], 678.08136, 677.4715, 676.727, 676.1977, 675.88776, 675.696, 675.52875, 675.6399
[0][15][2], 678.3292, 678.04065, 677.3929, 676.8126, 676.4649, 676.28033, 676.16, 676.3121
[0][15][3], 678.8748, 679.0778, 678.6973, 678.10486, 677.7194, 677.59784, 677.70197, 678.08344
[0][15][4], 679.7213, 680.37616, 680.38824, 679.9477, 679.61835, 679.6019, 679.8774, 680.34766
[0][15][5], 680.678, 681.4867, 681.84973, 681.73254, 681.5897, 681.6101, 681.8477, 682.18225
[0][15][6], 681.657, 682.3016, 682.8472, 683.06226, 683.09906, 682.98083, 682.893, 683.06445
[0][15][7], 682.7799, 683.03394, 683.59875, 684.0925, 684.14044, 683.6865, 683.20715, 683.25104
[0][16][0], 872.15247, 875.8923, 879.8187, 882.02814, 882.46576, 882.46954, 882.85126, 883.1807
[0][16][1], 877.0001, 880.11096, 883.71674, 885.3156, 884.8133, 884.1991, 885.0534, 886.70575
[0][16][2], 882.46216, 884.02374, 886.41223, 887.09863, 885.7347, 884.46387, 885.2397, 887.4753
[0][16][3], 885.3889, 885.27704, 886.39856, 886.4322, 884.7113, 883.0353, 883.36115, 885.40265
[0][16][4], 885.0074, 884.0188, 884.4739, 884.63434, 883.3711, 881.92377, 881.9412, 883.43195
[0][16][5], 883.21185, 882.2519, 882.7181, 883.4307, 883.264, 882.8126, 883.18823, 884.2301
[0][16][6], 881.83685, 881.3681, 882.02576, 883.06024, 883.91437, 884.8818, 886.2607, 887.2179
[0][16][7], 881.4078, 881.48987, 882.09906, 882.87494, 884.0972, 886.24695, 888.6479, 889.6661
```

I **try this code**. But idea where i am doing mistake?

```
 years = dir; years(1:2) = []; 
 for yy = 1:length(years)
     months = dir; months(1:2) = []; 
     for mm = 1:length(months)
         file = dir('*.txt');
         fid = fopen(file(1).name);
 Data = textscan(fid,'%s','Delimiter','\n');
 Data = Data{1};
 Data(1:13) = [];  % This Deletes the Header
 FooterInd = find(strncmp(Data,'pottmp',6)); FooterInd = FooterInd(1);
 Data(FooterInd:end) = [];
 fid = fopen(sprintf('New Text Document.txt',k),'wt'); % Here i am trying to export
    fprintf(fid,' \t \t \n');
    fprintf(fid,'%.3f\t%.3f\t%.3f\n',Data); % not sure what is going here?
    fclose(fid);
     end
 end
```

Comment: MATLAB is not the best tool for manipulating text files. That said I would read in each file (one at a time) into memory using fileread() and then use regexprep() to remove any lines that don't start with a "[", then write that string back out to a new file.

Comment: what's the error message?

Comment: "Index exceeds matrix dimensions". this is an error

Comment: On which line do you get the error?

Comment: Justin.. Please post in formatted code form. Actually  file is creating 0*1 structure . Check it please

Comment: when i manually use it i got error in file = dir('*.txt'); and below.I am not a big programmer

Comment: You have to define the exact directory to function `dir`. You call it three times, and you want it to dir you three different directories, but how Matlab should know which directory you need each time...? For example, you can write `months=dir([pwd '\' years(yy)]);`

Comment: i do not understand. Please post in answer after editing my code. Thanks

Comment: If you do it on one file, you get the desired result? The problem is only with the loop over the folders and files?

Comment: i still do not get.. I try first three commands from the code and after getting head ache post this here. Try to give in the form of answer. And i am surprise to see some one give this question -ve vote :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your immediate issue is that you read all of your data in as *strings* and not numbers. This means that when writing your data back *out* you want to use strings rather than numbers. Currently you try to write `Data` back to the file with:

```
fprintf(fid,'%.3f\t%.3f\t%.3f\n',Data); % not sure what is going here?
```

But the `%f` indicates that you think that `Data` contains numeric data. Instead you will want to use the following format string.

```
fprintf(fid, '%s\n', Data)
```

This will write it back just like you read it in (as a string).

**Addendum**

As far as going through the directory tree and finding all of these files, you have to be careful because it looks like you are calling `dir` from within the same directory multiple times.

You will probably want something like this:

```
basedir = 'E:\meta data\new\data _thesis\NCEP\potential_temperature';

% Helper function to remove '.' and '..' and get directories
get_dirs = @(s){s(~ismember({s.name}, {'.', '..'}) & [s.isdir]).name};

% Find year directories and turn into full paths
yeardirs = get_dirs(dir(basedir));
yeardirs = cellfun(@(x)fullfile(basedir, x), yeardirs, 'uni', 0);

for k = 1:numel(yeardirs)
    % Find month directories and turn into full paths
    monthdirs = get_dirs(dir(yeardirs{k}));
    monthdirs = cellfun(@(x)fullfile(yeardirs{k}, x), monthdirs, 'uni', 0);

    for m = 1:numel(monthdirs)
        % Full path to the file that you would like to load
        filename = fullfile(monthdirs{m}, 'New Text Document.txt');

        % Load and process file here
        fid = fopen(filename, 'rb');
        Data = textscan(fid, '%s', 'Delimiter', '\n', 'HeaderLines', 13);
        fclose(fid);

        % Remove footer
        Data = Data{1};
        footerRow = regexp(Data, '^pottmp');
        isfooter = ~cellfun(@isempty, footerRow);

        footerInd = find(isfooter, 1, 'first');
        Data = Data(1:(footerInd-1));

        % Save the result
        [folder, fname, ext] = fileparts(filename);
        outname = fullfile(folder, ['modified.', fname, ext]);
        fid = fopen(outname, 'wt');
        fprintf(fid,' \t \t \r\n');
        fprintf(fid, '%s\r\n', Data{:});
        fclose(fid);
    end
end
```

> **NOTE**: *NEVER* use `files(1:2) = [];` to remove the `.` and `..` directories. The result of `dir` is listed alphabetically and there *are* directories and files that could be listed before those two so you need to explicitly check to see if the values are actually `.` and `..`.

Comment: Suever please adjust my portion of code which remove header and footer from the text file and then save the save text file after editing in the same folder

Comment: @MuhammadUsmanSaleem You really could have applied what I posted to your own problem. In the future try to think about the post and try to arrive at the answer yourself. I have *this time* updated the post with code specific to your post.

Comment: ok. Thanks Surever... But i am getting this error "Error using dir
Function is not defined for 'cell' inputs."

Comment: @MuhammadUsmanSaleem Made a small update. Also if you're getting an error a full error message is useful

Comment: "Error using textscan
Invalid file identifier.  Use fopen to generate a valid file identifier."   and all files are with header and footer :(

Comment: @MuhammadUsmanSaleem That means it can't find the file defined in `filename`. Add a `disp(filename)` before opening the file to see what file it's trying to open

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106936/discussion-between-muhammad-usman-saleem-and-suever).

Comment: Please update this code as it is only producing "New Text Document.txt.new" which is new format.. It is not txt file format. This file is not opening in text.

Comment: And Please update it so that i produce output txt file as i demand in my question.

Comment: @MuhammadUsmanSaleem So you want to overwrite the current file? I updated it to do that. It *is* still a text format, it just has a different file extension. Also you aren't *demanding* anything. Please be aware that we are **volunteering** our time to help you out.

Comment: No, I do not want to write current file. Save it any name which able me to understand it is header and footer remove file. After running this code, it update all my original files. When i look into txt file, header and footers are remove but data is scatter(with out any order) please look at my output file, data after removing header and footer look line with original. But when copy and past this text file data into excel it looks aline. Please update such manner after removing header and footer it looks aline with my data(Please see my output in my question)

Comment: And @Suever, how can i say thanks to your kind effort? I know i have take two very important days from you. I have no words for your kind assistance...Always stay bless

Comment: @MuhammadUsmanSaleem Just made an update that should help. You could say thanks by selecting this as the answer once it works for you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107164/discussion-between-muhammad-usman-saleem-and-suever).